# Solr not searching (Very basic example)

Tags: solr, lucene

**Solr version :**
4.2.1

**Objective:**
I am trying to get a very simplistic Solr example off the ground

**So far:**
Installed solr
Was able to run the example\tutorial  successfully http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/tutorial.html

**Next:**
Now I am trying to create my own schema
I have created a schema : http://pastebin.com/vj4ATa8d
And a Test Doc:http://pastebin.com/7fvZ5GTQ
I have added the doc to Solr using the command
*java -jar post.jar testdoc.xml*

**What’s working:**
In Solr Admin- I can see the schema
I can see one document uploaded
I can go to Admin console and query as follows:
Specify q as “:”. This works- shows the document

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection2/select?q=*%3A*&wt=xml&indent=true
```

**What does not work:**
If I give q as Nashua- I see no results
This is the default search field
Other attributes didn't work either

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection2/select?q=Nashua&wt=xml&indent=true
```

The debug response http://pastebin.com/fTneyEba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either copy your fields into the default search field (in this case text) or qualify your query with the field you want to search against:

```
.../select?q=city:Nashua&wt=xml&indent=true
```

Things to read up on:

1. Default Search Field
2. Copy Fields

Both are documented here:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml